# How to change a module variable from another module?

Tags: python, import, module

Suppose I have a package named `bar`, and it contains `bar.py`:

```
a = None

def foobar():
    print a
```

and `__init__.py`:

```
from bar import a, foobar
```

Then I execute this script:

```
import bar

print bar.a
bar.a = 1
print bar.a
bar.foobar()
```

Here's what I expect:

```
None
1
1
```

Here's what I get:

```
None
1
None
```

Can anyone explain my misconception?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

You are using `from bar import a`. `a` becomes a symbol in the global scope of the importing module (or whatever scope the import statement occurs in).

When you assign a new value to `a`, you are just changing which value `a` points too, not the actual value. Try to import `bar.py` directly with `import bar` in `__init__.py` and conduct your experiment there by setting `bar.a = 1`. This way, you will actually be modifying `bar.__dict__['a']` which is the 'real' value of `a` in this context.

It's a little convoluted with three layers but `bar.a = 1` changes the value of `a` in the module called `bar` that is actually derived from `__init__.py`. It does not change the value of `a` that `foobar` sees because `foobar` lives in the actual file `bar.py`. You could set `bar.bar.a` if you wanted to change that.

This is one of the dangers of using the `from foo import bar` form of the `import` statement: it splits `bar` into two symbols, one visible globally from within `foo` which starts off pointing to the original value and a different symbol visible in the scope where the `import` statement is executed. Changing a where a symbol points doesn't change the value that it pointed too.

This sort of stuff is a killer when trying to `reload` a module from the interactive interpreter.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer probably just saved me several hours of looking for the culprit.

Comment: Looks like even the `bar.bar.a` approach won't help much in most use cases. It's probably a weak idea to mix compile or module loading and runtime assignments because you'll end up confusing yourself (or others that use your code). Especially in languages that behave somewhat inconsistently about it, like python arguably does.

Answer (score 33):

One source of difficulty with this question is that you have a program named `bar/bar.py`: `import bar` imports either `bar/__init__.py` or `bar/bar.py`, depending on where it is done, which makes it a little cumbersome to track which `a` is `bar.a`.

Here is how it works:

The key to understanding what happens is to realize that in your `__init__.py`,

```
from bar import a
```

in effect does something like

```
a = bar.a
# … where bar = bar/bar.py (as if bar were imported locally from __init__.py)
```

and defines a new variable (`bar/__init__.py:a`, if you wish).  Thus, your `from bar import a` in `__init__.py` binds name `bar/__init__.py:a` to the original `bar.py:a` object (`None`).  This is why you can do `from bar import a as a2` in `__init__.py`: in this case, it is clear that you have both `bar/bar.py:a` and a *distinct* variable name `bar/__init__.py:a2` (in your case, the names of the two variables just happen to both be `a`, but they still live in different namespaces: in `__init__.py`, they are `bar.a` and `a`).

Now, when you do

```
import bar

print bar.a
```

you are accessing variable `bar/__init__.py:a` (since `import bar` imports your `bar/__init__.py`). This is the variable you modify (to 1). You are not touching the contents of variable `bar/bar.py:a`. So when you subsequently do

```
bar.foobar()
```

you call `bar/bar.py:foobar()`, which accesses variable `a` from `bar/bar.py`, which is still `None` (when `foobar()` is defined, it binds variable names once and for all, so the `a` in `bar.py` is `bar.py:a`, not any other `a` variable defined in another module—as there might be many `a` variables in all the imported modules).  Hence the last `None` output.

Conclusion: it is best to avoid any ambiguity in `import bar`, by *not* having any `bar/bar.py` module (since `bar.__init__.py` makes directory `bar/` a package already, that you can also import with `import bar`).

Answer (score 24):

To put another way:
Turns out this misconception is very easy to make. 
[It is sneakily defined in the Python language reference:](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) the use of *object* instead of *symbol*. I would suggest that the Python language reference make this more clear and less sparse..

> The `from` form does not bind the module name: it goes through the
>   list of identifiers, looks each one of them up in the module found in
>   step (1), and binds the name in the local namespace to the **object** thus
>   found.

**HOWEVER:**

*When you import, you import the current value of the imported symbol and add it to your namespace as defined.* **You are not importing a reference, you are effectively importing a value.**

Thus, to get the updated value of `i`, you must import a variable that holds a reference to that symbol.

In other words, importing is NOT like an `import` in JAVA, `external` declaration in C/C++ or even a `use` clause in PERL.

Rather, the following statement in Python:

```
from some_other_module import a as x
```

is more *like* the following code in K&R C:

```
extern int a; /* import from the EXTERN file */

int x = a;
```

(caveat: in the Python case, "a" and "x" are essentially a reference to the actual value: you're not copying the INT, you're copying the reference address)

Comment: Actually, I find the Python's way of `import` much more cleaner than Java's, because namespaces/scopes shall always be kept properly separated and never interfere with each other in unexpected ways.  Like here: Altering a binding of an object to a name in a namespace (read: assing something to a module's global property) never affects other namespaces (read: the reference which was imported) in Python.  But does so in Java, etc.  In Python you only need to understand what is imported, while in Java, you also must understand the other module in case, it alters this imported value later on.

Comment: I have to disagree quite strenuously. Importing/including/using has a long history of using the reference form and not the value form in nust about every other language.

Comment: Dammit, I hit return… there is this an expectation of import by reference (as per @OP). In fact, a new Python programmer, no matter how experienced, has to be told this in the "look out" sort of way. That should never happen: based on common usage, Python took the wrong path. Create an"import value" if need be, but don't conflate symbols with values at time of import.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `sys.modules` to see what's really happening. When importing a module, Python will create a new entry for a module object in `sys.modules`.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcrLe.png) is my vscode debugger screenshot after executing the statement `bar.a = 1` . As you can see, it changed the `a` in module `bar` but not the `a` in module `bar.bar` .

It had to do with the concepts of namespace, mutable and immutable objects. For example, if I change `bar.bar.a` with an empty list instead of `None`, then append something in `bar`. You can see all of the `a` will change as shown in [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UE9p6.png).

Answer (score 0):

This could be either useful or a "gotcha", but you can modify the value of the variable available in the imported module by using the `global` keyword.

In `foo.py`:

```py
a = 1

def change_a(value):
    global a
    a = value
    return a
    
def use_a():
    return a
```

And in `main.py`:

```py
from foo import a, change_a, use_a

print(f"Initial value of a: {a}")            # 1
print(f"use_a: {use_a()}")                   # 1
print(f'change_a: {change_a("new value")}')  # "new value"
print(f"a: {a}")                             # 1
print(f"use_a: {use_a()}")                   # "new value"
```

Note that the imported value of `a` is unchanged!