# Python 3 NOT updating variables in a nested package (”recursive” relative imports used)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I’m refactoring a large *procedural* program (implemented as many files in one folder) and using packages to group the files into an object oriented structure.  This application uses tKinter (probable red herring) and is being developed using PyDev on Eclipse Kepler (on & for Win7).

It does use some classes but converting the package structure (see below) into classes is NOT the preferred solution (unless it’s the only reasonable way to get what I want).

At the bottom of a 4 level  package nest I’ve defined a constant (“conA”), a function (“funcB”), and a variable (“varC”).  Going from the bottom up, the `__init__.py` file of every level (inside the (nested) folder that implements the package) contains:

```
from .levelbelowModuleName  import conA
from .levelbelowModuleName  import funcB
from .levelbelowModuleName  import varC
```

so that the “recursive” imports make the “level4” entities visible by their “level4” names at all levels.

In the higher level packages “read only” references to all entities do not cause warning/error messages.   No problem so far.

But when trying to update “varC “ inside a higher level package I get two warnings:  1) an “unused import: varC” warning at the top of the file, and, 2) inside the updating function (which has a “global varC” statement) an  “unused variable: varC” warning at the “varC =” line.  OK so far since the two “varC”s  aren’t being associated (but see nasty side issue below).

I thought (inferred from Chapter 23/24 of Lutz’s “Learning Python” book ) that imported names - at all levels - would refer to the same object (address) - and therefore that updating a variable that resides in a “nephew” (brothers child) package would work.   Elevating “varC” to the nearest common ancestor package (immediate parent of the problem package, grandparent of the “nephew”) seems to be a valid workaround (it eliminates the warnings) – but doing this destroys the purpose of the object-oriented package structure.

Converting to absolute imports did not help.  Renaming/aliasing “varC” (by using “as” on the imports) did not help.

BTW, The update line used in the higher level module is “varC = X.getTable()”; this returns a matrix (list of lists) of tKinter IntVars from a custom class.

The nasty side issue:  a “read only” reference to “varC” anywhere in the problem file, e.g. “print(varC)”  whether at the top of the file or inside the function, will eliminate both warnings, hiding the problem.

Is there a way of having my cake and eating it too?  Is there a “non-class” way of having “varC” reside at level4 and still be updateable by the higher level packages?  Or is using a common ancestor the only simple-to-understand *”non-class”* approach that will work?

P.S. Of the related questions that were suggested when entering this question, none seem to apply.  A similar, but simpler (not nested) question is:
[How to change a module variable from another module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536620/how-to-change-a-module-variable-from-another-module)

Added 2015-03-27:

Here are two Eclipse screenshots of the actual files.  (For those not familiar with Eclipse,  `__init__.py` appears as a tab that has the package name.)  The first shot shows the recursive imports (from bottom to top).  The second shows the function, the "unused import" (yellow triangle) warning for "SiteSpecificReports".  The line highlighted in blue is where the "unused variable" warning was (it has mysteriously disappeared).

Ignore everything to do with LongitudeReports, it's essentially a clone of MessageCountReports. For clarity, I've hidden all code that is not relevant to the problem (e.g. tKinter calls). Ignore the red "X" on the file names; all are tKinter "init time" type mismatches that disappear when the code is run (as per comment above "SiteSpecificReports" in `__init__.py` for MessageCountReports).

In the module hierarchy the problem file is highlighted in grey. "A_Mainline.py" is the execute point, everything below that is the code being refactored (some has already been moved into the packages above that file). Finally, excluding CZQX, all subpackages beneath "SiteSpecific" are placeholders and only contain an empty `__init__.py` file.

[image: Shows all Recursive imports]

[image: Teh function with the problem(and warning message)]

Updated 2105-10-23

The point behind all of this was to keep file sizes to a reasonable level by splitting each module into several source files.

The accepted answer (and it's included link) provided the clue I needed.  My problem was that when I refactored a file/module into several subfiles (each containing the variable definitions and the functions that *modified* them) I was thinking of each subfile as being a class-like "black box" object instead of being, somewhat more correctly, a simple "insert this file into the higher level file" command (like an editor "paste" command).

My thinking was that the recursive imports would, in effect, recursively promote the addresses of the lower level variables into the higher level "*init.py*" namespaces, thus making those variables visible to all other subfiles of the module (who would only *reference* those variables) - and allowing me to have my cake (localized definitions) and eat it too (variables available at the topmost level).  This approach has worked for me in other *compiled* languages, notably ADA 83.

When creating subfiles it seems that for a variable to be visible to other subfiles you need to define it in the *topmost* file instead of the *bottommost* one - which defeats the "object-ish" approach I was trying to use.  Kind of a bummer that this approach doesn't work since the location of the variables makes it awkward to reuse a subfile in other modules.  Converting each file to a class should accomplish what I was after - but that seems really pointless when all you need is the "insert this code block here" effect.

Anyway, the important thing is that everything's working now.

Comment: would you like to give an image of your directory structure and implied files (or Ascii art in the code mode), and the way you declare your constant,  functions vars and so on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the distinction between *names* and *values* in python. Names live in namespaces and point to values. When you say:

```
from .blah import Foo
```

you're creating a *new* name in your current namespace, that points to the same *value* that `Foo` points to in the `blah` namespace. If after that you say:

```
Foo = 1
```

That changes your *local namespace's* `Foo` to point to a `1`, but it does nothing to `blah.Foo` -- you would have to explicitly say `blah.Foo = 1` to change the name `Foo` that lives in `blah`.

This [blog post](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) is a good read to clarify.