# How to change the value of a module variable from within an object of another module?

Tags: python

**Summary**: I have a script which exposes<sup>(1)</sup> a `dict` and I need to modify this `dict` from with another module

**Note**: Two great answers to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536620/how-to-change-a-module-variable-from-another-module) explain a lot about variables scoping between modules but I fail to understand how this applies to my case.

In the code below, I expected that I will be able to modify the `mainmodule.py` variable  `container` from within `submodule.py`, which is not the case. Why?

How should I address the `mainmodule` instance of `container` from within `submodule`?

The code for the main script

```
# mainmodule.py
# the main script which ultimately exposes the module variable 'container'
import submodule

container = dict()

class MainClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sub = submodule.SubClass()

    def set(self, number):
        print("main: container was {container}".format(container=container))
        container['x'] = number
        print("main: container is {container}".format(container=container))


    def call(self, number):
        self.sub.set(number)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mc = MainClass()
    # updating container from this script
    mc.set(1)
    # updating container from another module
    mc.call(2)
    # again from this script, to check the updates
    mc.set(3)
```

The code for the imported module

```
# submodule.py
import mainmodule

class SubClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def set(self, number):
        print("sub: container was {container}".format(container=mainmodule.container))
        mainmodule.container['x'] = number
        print("sub: container is {container}".format(container=mainmodule.container))
```

The output is

```
main: container was {}
main: container is {'x': 1}
sub: container was {}
sub: container is {'x': 2}
main: container was {'x': 1}
main: container is {'x': 3}
```

<sup>(1)</sup>The actual code uses `bottle` to provide `container` via  `json.dumps()`

Comment: you could explicitly pass a reference to `container` to each of the methods that mutates it

Comment: Do you mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29701972/python-global-variables-in-multiple-files/29702401#29702401?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Staring at your code for a bit, I think i know what might be throwing you off.  The python script invoked as `python foo.py` will end up being a module (in `sys.modules`) called `__main__`.  That means the bottom bit of your `mainmodule.py` shows is loaded and compiled and run once, with `__name__ == "__main__"`, which causes some things to happen.  That module imports `submodule`, which has not been imported yet, so that gets loaded and run.

`submodule` in turn tries to import `mainmodule`.  Although that file has been executed before, it's not known to the interpreter by that module name,  so `mainmodule.py` gets run again, this time with `__name__ == "mainmodule"` (which isn't the same as `"__main__"`, so the `if` suite at the bottom is skipped).

That means you have *two* copies of `container`,  one in the module who's name is `__main__`, and one in a module named `mainmodule`.  The fact that both are from a file called `./mainmodule.py` is not relevant.

There are a few ways to fix this.  One is to always *import* the real immediately, as in:

```
# mainmodule.py
import submodule
class Foo:
    pass
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import mainmodule
    mainmodule.Foo()
```

Another option is to move the code inside the `if` to another file.