# Python design pattern

Tags: python

I have a module that does something one of two ways:

```
project/
|-- main.py
+-- module.py
```

**main.py**

```
import module

module.do_something()
module.set_method(module.WAY_2)
module.do_something()
```

**module.py**

```
WAY_1 = "the_first_way"
WAY_2 = "the_second_way"

method = WAY_1 # by default

def set_method(new_method):
    method = new_method

def do_something_the_first_way():
    print "Doing it the first way"

def do_something_the_second_way():
    print "Doing it the second way"

def do_something():
    if method == WAY_1:
        do_something_the_first_way()
    if method == WAY_2:
        do_something_the_second_way()
```

When I run `main.py`, I get this output:

```
Doing it the first way
Doing it the first way
```

It looks like the `method` variable of `module.py` is not getting updated, even though we try to set it with `set_method` from `main.py`. I have an idea of what's happening here based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536620/how-to-change-a-module-variable-from-another-module), but I want to know what the best way to fix the problem is.

What is the most elegant, Pythonic way to solve this problem?

Comment: `set_method` isn't changing the global `method` variable, for starters. It's not really doing anything, as of now

Comment: Thanks, that helped me solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

By default, any assignment in a function creates a function-local variable; it does not update a global by the same name. You need to define it as global explicitly:

```
def set_method(new_method):
    global method
    method = new_method
```

Comment: Thanks! I have fixed the problem.