# Global variables in a Python module spontaneously reset

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have part of a program written in Python 3.5 and started by testing the first two modules. I managed to isolate a problem in one of the modules where it appears that two global variables are switching back to their original values for no reason that I can understand. One of these global variables (`event_count`) is used in only a single function (grep shows the string "event_count" doesn't appear anywhere else in any of my *.py files), yet the value of the variable changes between calls to the function. If I add print statements for the other global variable in this module, it also reverts to it's original value at the same moment. Moving `event_count` to another module (replacing it with `sensorlogic.event_count` in `eventcount()` and moving the initialization to the other module) makes the behavior go away, so I have a fix but no understanding.

Here is all of the code that uses `event_count`, in module `sensoreval`:

```
event_count = 0

def eventcount(increment):
    global event_count
    print("entering eventcount, increment =", increment,
          ", event_count =", event_count)
    event_count += increment
    print("leaving eventcount, event_count =", event_count)
    return event_count
```

If I run the following code segment:

```
    e.setvalue(1)
    print("I am at marker #1")
    eventcount(0)
```

(the last action in `e.setvalue()` is a call to `eventcount(0)`) it produces this output:

```
entering eventcount, increment = 0 , event_count = 4
leaving eventcount, event_count = 4
I am at marker #1
entering eventcount, increment = 0 , event_count = 0
leaving eventcount, event_count = 0
```

I have tried trimming down the two modules to something of reasonable size, but the problem keeps going away when I do so. I'll keep working on that. Since I've never used Python 3 before, and only have a little Python 2.7 experience I assume I'm doing something stupid, I just have no idea what.

I believe that my example is different from some of the related posts that have been pointed out in that the variable `event_count` is global only so it will be static. It is used only in this single function. The string "event_count" doesn't appear anywhere else in this or any other module.

---

After many edit/rerun iterations, I have a managably small example that demonstrates what is happening. It involves two modules with a total of 8 lines of code. The first module, `a.py`, is `__main__`:

```
import b
c = 0
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    b.init()
    print("c =", c)
```

The second module is `b.py`:

```
import a
def init():
    a.c = 1
```

Running `a.py` produces the output:

```
c = 0
```

I expected `c` to still be 1 from the `a.c = 1` in `b.py`.

Also, I tried to reduce this further by deleting the `if __name__ == '__main__'` from `a.py`, but then the example no longer runs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\a.py", line 1, in <module>
    import b
  File "...\b.py", line 1, in <module>
    import a
  File "...\a.py", line 3, in <module>
    b.init()
AttributeError: module 'b' has no attribute 'init'
```

I can't explain that, either, but it seems likely to be related.

---

Following Mata's lead, I believe that the following code shows what's going on. There are three modules involved. `a.py`:

```
print("__name__ =", __name__)
import b
print("__name__ =", __name__)
def f(): pass
print(f)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("f is b.a.f?", f is b.a.f)
```

`b.py`:

```
import a
```

`c.py`:

```
import a
import b
print("__name__ =", __name__)
print("a.f is b.a.f?", a.f is b.a.f)
```

You can see the problem by running `a.py`, giving the result:

```
__name__ = __main__
__name__ = a
__name__ = a
<function f at 0x0000021A4A947840>
__name__ = __main__
<function f at 0x0000021A484E0400>
f is b.a.f? False
```

Running `c.py` so that `__main__` isn't part of the import cycle results in:

```
__name__ = a
__name__ = a
<function f at 0x000001EA101B7840>
__name__ = __main__
a.f is b.a.f? True
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)

Comment: This looks relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3536620/4996248

Comment: There must be a clue in whatever it is that you trim that makes the problem go away.  Also strange, your output says `event_count` not actually incremented.

Comment: I'll wager, if you run `eventcount(4)` followed by `eventcount(0)` that you will get the result that you expect. So the error must lie in `e.setvalue()`

Comment: Quote: "the last action in e.setvalue() is a call to eventcount(0)". What is the point of that?

Comment: Originally `event_count` was a much more widely used global variable. I replaced it with a function in the hope of learning why things weren't working. @Terry: The function simply returns the value of `event_count` if its argument is zero, or changes `event_count` if the argument is non-zero. Thus `eventcount(0)` simply returns the value of `event_count` and as a side effect produces the printed output shown. @Rolf: This side effect is the only reason that there is a call in `e.setvalue()`, it was part of my tracking down the moment when the value changed.

Comment: I would recommend against using evencount(0) to do something different than evencount(non-zero). Just make a new function if you want to return the value of even_count. Functions/methods should do one thing.

Comment: @Albert I completely agree, but I was trying to get the number of references to `event_count` down to an absolute minimum in order to isolate where the change in value was happening. This narrowed its use to a single function, but the variable is still changing unexpectedly. At this point I know how to avoid the problem, but I would like to better understand it to avoid stepping into it again.

Comment: Is this run from `__main__`? What is `e`? The module may be imported twice, once as `__main__`, once as `some_module` (if it was named so), so you would end up with `__main__.event_count` being used by code from `__main__` and `some_module.event_count` from other modules that import it as `some_module`.

Comment: Now that I've let Mata's comment sink in, he is exactly right. The first module was imported twice and references to it's global variables and functions from other packages pointed to the "other" copy, while the copy in `__main__` remained unchanged. Lesson: If there is a cycle of imports, then don't reference globals in `__main__` from other modules. Or even better keep `__main__` out of the cycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a look at your two-module example step-by-step. The behavior there is expected, but initially confusing and probably explains what is going on pretty well in the other cases.

If you run `a` as a script, it is not imported as `a` into `sys.modules`, but rather as `__main__`. The first statement is `import b`, which creates an empty module object `sys.modules['b']` and begins initializing it.

The first line of `b` imports `a` again. Normally, a module object under `sys.modules['a']` would be found, but in this case, you are running `a` as a script, so the initial import happened under a different name. Since the name of `a` is `a` and not `__main__` this time, `a.c` is set to zero and nothing else happens.

Now execution returns to `b`. It now creates a function `init`, which sets `sys.modules['a'].c` to one. I wrote out the reference to the `a` module very explicitly because this is the root cause of your discrepancy.

Once `b` is imported, execution returns back to `a`, but not `sys.modules['a']`. The next line, `c = 0` actually sets `sys.modules['__main__'].c` to zero. Hopefully you see the problem at this point. The next line calls `b.init`, which sets `sys.modules['a']` to one. Then you print `sys.modules['__main__']`, which is zero, as expected.

To verify the correctness of this exposition, try adding a print statement

```
print(sys.modules['a'].c)
```

You will get `1`. Also, `sys.modules['a'] is sys.modules['__main__'].c` will be `False`. The easiest way to get around this is not to initialize members of other modules in a given module's import.

Your specific case is documented here: http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm#using-modules-as-scripts.

**Additional Resources**

You can get a lot more information on the gritty details of the import system here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html. Various traps and caveats of imports are described here: http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html.