# Python: change global variable from within another file

Tags: python

In my main class I use a global variable ADDRESS that is defined in another file called config.py.
I want to change the value of ADDRESS from within my main class, by calling a function in config.py.

In my main class I have:

```
from config import ADDRESS, change_address
change_address("192.168.10.100")
print("new address " + ADDRESS)
```

In my config file I have the following:

```
ADDRESS = "0.0.0.0"

def change_address(address):
    global ADDRESS
    ADDRESS = address
    print("changed address to: " + ADDRESS)
```

The print statement in my config file correctly prints the new address of 192.168.10.100.
However, the print statement in my main class prints 0.0.0.0.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Your `import` binds a new local variable `ADDRESS` to the string that the `ADDRESS` variable in config refers to. When you call `change_address()` the `ADDRESS` variable in config now refers to a different string. Your own local variable still refers to the original string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All that `from config import ADDRESS, change_address` does is take `ADDRESS` and `change_address` from your `config` module's namespace and dumps it into your current module's name-space. Now, if you reassign the value of `ADDRESS` in `config`'s namespace, it won't be seen by the current module - that's how name-spaces work. It is like doing the following:

```
>>> some_namespace = {'a':1}
>>> globals().update(some_namespace)
>>> a
1
>>> some_namespace
{'a': 1}
>>> some_namespace['a'] = 99
>>> a
1
>>> some_namespace
{'a': 99}
```

The simplest solution? Don't clobber name-spaces:

```
import config
config.change_address("192.168.10.100")
print("new address " + config.ADDRESS)
```

Comment: You were quicker ;) I just wanted to add this link, since it describes this common problem: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules

Comment: worked perfectly :) thank you @gonczor. Although not a duplicate question I believe, I found same solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536620/how-to-change-a-module-variable-from-another-module

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you try not to change the global state in a module. Instead, I would re-write the code such that `ADDRESS` in config.py doesn't change. If the configuration for your application can change from invocation to invocation I would change config to be something like:

```
ADDRESS = '0.0.0.0'

def get_default_config():
    return {'address': ADDRESS, 'some_other_config_value': 'foo'}
```

Then in main I would do:

```
app_config = config.get_default_config()
app_config = "192.168.10.100"
print("new address " + app_config['address']
```

As a general rule it isn't a good idea to change the value of variables/constants in other modules.

NOTE: You could also create a config class as well, so that you could access configuration values like config.address.

I recommend that you read the stackexchange post [Why is Global State so Evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil)