# Setting a variable for use in an import in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a bit of a weird use case where I need to have as little code as possible in my primary script.  (many inexperienced people will edit hundreds of these scripts spread out amongst hundreds of devices)

I am trying to optionally set a variable which will be used in an import, but without forcing these many people to remember to pass it to a function every time.

Here's my pseudo code, how can I make this work?

```
myimport.py
-----------
isdebug = False
def myfunction()
    if isdebug:
         print("do something")
      
         
mymain.py
---------
import myimport
myimport.isdebug = True   # I want this variable set in myimport.py
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. What are you asking?

Comment: This should work. For more infos: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3536638/12749132